# Repetitive information on different forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I do not want the customer to keep writing the same basic information on different forms for example; their names, address or phone number.

How can this information be automatically uploaded on the next form?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making users to fill the form again and again with **same basic information** as you said in your question?
It is a bad practice. You must not write the same code (or forms in this case) again and again. Also as per user's perspective, it would be a bad practice if he must have to fill the same info again and again.

**Solution**

Use a single form to collect user's information at one time. In case if you need information in step by step manner, don't let him/her to repeat the **same** info. Ask him to fill only relevant info.

By this your users will be happy cos now they do not have to fill same basic info again and again on different forms. This will also let you keep your code clean and less complex. Also if you follow coding standards, you can call yourself a Good Programmer..